# How to count the number of results in multiple group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have an SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    ID
  , PERSON
  , STATE
  , VDATE
  , count(PERSON)
  , count(VDATE) 
from myTable  
group by 
    PERSON
  , STATE
  , VDATE;
```

I am interested in the VDATE. There could be records that have a blank VDATE and possibly more than VDATE.

My ideal result is a list where there is only one result from the previous select AND VDATE is null.

So for the following dataset

ID, PERSON, STATE, VDATE, count(PERSON), count(VDATE)

1234, 9000, ND, 2014-04-24, 1, 1

1235, 9000, ND, , 2, 2

1236, 9001, CA, , 2, 2

1237, 9002, CA, , 2, 2

1238, 9002, NV, , 2, 2

1239, 9003, MD, 2014-04-24, 2, 2

I would want 1236, 1237 and 1238 returned

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, this might be what you are describing:

```
select ID, PERSON, STATE, VDATE, count(PERSON), count(VDATE) 
from myTable  
where VDATE IS NOT NULL
group by PERSON, STATE, VDATE
UNION ALL
select NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, count(PERSON), 0
from myTable
where VDATE IS NULL;
```